# Can I use bootstrap navbar inside of carousel?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel, navbar

I am want to transform an existing webside using Typo3 (www.bernhard-malle.de) into a reponsive website using bootstrap. The contents will not change very often, therefore I can live without the advantages of a fullblown CMS.

I have used bootstrap before, so I believe I am quiet familiar with it. 
However in my new project, I have 5 pages with different colors for header and navbar on every page and, on top of it, I want it to be multi-lingual (English, German, French). I could do it with a dedicated website for each subtopic and for each language, but then I have to maintain 15 different pages.

Has anyone of you tried to put navbar contents inside of a bootstrap carousel page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can start from here and look how things are done
http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/bootstrap_package